# loop through all webpage's links and navigate again

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

using an EXCEL sheet i can do what i need...find all links in a page, navigate then find all links..and so on..i want to use instead an array...

```
    Set tb = doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(2)
For Each tr In tb.Rows
For Each td In tr.Cells
For Each L In td.getElementsByTagName("a")
If InStr(1, Trim(L.href), "sito/WebServlet?Ric=") > 0 Then '73
If InStr(1, Trim(L.href), "&Protocollo=T") > 0 Then '73
Else
If IsEmpty(Dynamic_array) Then
ReDim Dynamic_array(0)
Dynamic_array(0) = "https://sito.it" & Replace(L.href, "about:", "")
Else
ReDim Preserve Dynamic_array(0 To UBound(Dynamic_array) + 1)
Dynamic_array(UBound(Dynamic_array)) = "https://sito.it" & Replace(L.href, "about:", "")
End If
End If
End If
Next
Next
Next
```

Comment: Who uses *GoTo* to simulate a loop is is a sinner ;-) I can't see any sense in your code but you will know what you want to do I think. I wouldn't use a dynamic data structure to go through all links. If there is an issue you must start from the beginning. By using a temporary table you can start over from the link from which broken if the mechanic of the macro is right. But if you want to do it via a dynmaic data structure a dictionary is more flexible than an array. Mainly because you don't know how many links the macro will collect. https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Comment: i did it knowing it wasn't the best way...my aim was to try if it was possible...i do it using array and i'm able to store all links in the first tables' page..so the aim is to get each links, navigate , take all link from the page and add to the array...certain..using some loop...i'll be grateful if you have same suggesstion...pratical ones best.